# PHP - Highcharts - PDF

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, highcharts, mpdf

Estou usando Mpdf para fazer com que alguns valores que guardei em SESSIONS no php se tornem um relatório, até ai tudo bem, mas a pagina que quero transformar em relatório possui gráficos Js, do Highcharts, não sei como exportar esses gráficos diretamente para o relatório que sera em pdf.

Site: http://carboncal.org/view/brasil/

Passos: Clique em Carbono por filtro(menu) >> calcular carbono >> WHRC

Comment: Inclua algum código fonte do que você já fez para que possamos lhe ajudar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infelizmente o mpdf não suporta javascript, então para que você possa mostrar um highchart no seu pdf você terá que exportar ele em formato de imagem.

Um exemplo disto seria:

```
var hightchart = $('#container').highcharts().getSVG(); // Pega o highcharts e transforma em SVG.
```

Envia o resultado por ajax para o php, e depois incluía no seu mpdf:

```
$html = "Olha um gráfico: ". $_POST['hightchart '];

include 'lib/mpdf/mpdf.php';
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('exemplo.pdf', 'I');
```

Exemplo: [Transformando gráfico em imagem](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/fFPNP/)

Documentação: [Highcharts Chart.getSVG](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.getSVG)

Comment: Meu chart esta separado no projeto, como que eu pego o ID dele e levo la pro codigo Php onde esta o MPDF ? Devo guardar a variavel highchart com os valores do meu grafico e la no meu codigo Php, fazer a requisição via Ajax ?

Answer (score -1):

Pra gerar PDF tenta usar uma biblioteca chamada wkhtmltopdf, é um projeto interessante que transforma em PDF a página renderizada pelo webkit, motor de renderização do Google.

Caso os gráficos fiquem vazios, tente desabilitar as animações do highcharts.

Comment: Na web ? como integrar isso ao Php por exemplo ? rs

Comment: Tem que instalar o wkhtmltopdf no servidor, ou verificar se já está instalado. Depois usar uma biblioteca em PHP para criar os PDF. 

Exemplo:
https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

OBS: Se você estiver usando algum framework PHP, verifique se existe algum módulo do wkhtmltopdf disponível para ele.